# onBlur change textbox background color

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can i change my textbox background and border color if return true from the function ? if return false my textbox background border will change, but when return true it remain red color. how can i fix this ? any help will be appreciated.

### Javascript

```
function checkPostcode() 
{

    var message = "";

    if (document.mainform.POSTCODE.value.length != 5)
    {
        message += "Invalid entry. Postcode must be in 5 number.";
    }
    else
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < document.mainform.POSTCODE.value.length; i++)
        {
            var f = document.mainform.POSTCODE.value.charAt(i);
            if (!(parseFloat(f) >= 0) || !(parseFloat(f) <= 9))
            {
                var jdap = "no";
            }
        }

        if (jdap=="no")
        {
            message += "Invalid entry. Please enter numbers only.";
        }
    }

    if (message != "") 
    {
            document.getElementById("posterrMsg").innerHTML      = message;
            document.getElementById("posterrMsg").style.display  = "inline";
            document.getElementById("POSTCODE").style.border     = "thin solid red";
            document.getElementById("POSTCODE").style.background = "#FFCECE";
            document.mainform.POSTCODE.value = "";
            document.mainform.POSTCODE.focus();
            return false;
    }
    else{

            document.getElementById("posterrMsg").innerHTML         = "";
            document.getElementById("posterrMsg").style.display     = "";
            document.getElementById("POSTCODE").style.border        = "thin solid #CCCCCCC";
            document.getElementById("POSTCODE").style.background    = "FFFFFF";
        return true;
    }

}
```

### HTML

```
 <label id="posterrMsg" class="errMsg"></label> 
 <input type="text" name="POSTCODE" id="POSTCODE" value="<%=POSTCODE%>" onblur="checkPostcode();" maxlength="5" />
```

Comment: Quickest solution is to add a class to the element when true happens either within the function or refactor the code a bit and let another function call this one and then check. Vice versa with false value. This can be done with VanillaJS.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
document.getElementById("POSTCODE").style.border = "thin solid #CCCCCCC";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("POSTCODE").style.border = "";
```

Comment: thanks @chop , It's worked ! i try to do the same for background it working also.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
document.getElementById("POSTCODE").className = "validPostcode";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("POSTCODE").className = "invalidPostcode";
```

If you want to add more styling.

Both are valid options here.

I would refactor your code a bit and maybe create an outer function which calls checkPostcode for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Use !== so

```
if (message !== "")
```

so that you are checking the same type and value.

You also had a couple of typeos in your background colours.

See working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vd1jLpr6/1/)